# What are all the given variants, in German, of "moralisch"?

Tags: prefix

Studying Nietzsche, one of the German words that I feel is underappreciated, and I wanted to confirm the meaning of, is "außer/aussermoralisch".  In comparison to "unmoralisch" or other variations on "moralisch", can I say, without a doubt, that "aussermoralisch" is not only a defined distinction/word, but also is easily-and-only translatable as "extra-moral", when translated into English?

Depending on the answer, how would one, in German, distinctly determine "amoral", "nonmoral", and "extra-moral"??

Please respond with more than 5 sentences.

Comment: So if I edit my question, will I get an answer from you?  Everything has it's standards, I guess:  I'll fix it.

Comment: @planetmaker and the request could be phrased differently. Yes, there’s the proverbial German bluntness, but it’s usually perceived quite harshly in an English text. In case of doubt, re-read the CoC, take a deep breath and walk away.

Comment: The second question should be asked separately.

Comment: @Stephie: Wow, it's a German thing? This whole time I was thinking it was an internet thing :) Anyway, it even says "be nice" in the comment header, but if someone in the English SE asked "wut wuz shakespears First play?" I'd think "This guy has far more serious issues." When you ask a question here you're asking strangers to spend time and effort to help you, so to me it's understandable if they become annoyed when it looks like you've put in none of your own effort. But you're right that text can offend when no offense is meant, and an effort should be made to avoid that.

Comment: We should keep in mind that some people will have questions about a particular German word but no intention to learn the language. Which is fine. That said, ß is a form of s and has nothing to do with b or β ;)

Comment: Aside from the question of politeness, which is quite subjective, I would encourage everyone **to correct spelling mistakes silently by simply editing the post**, as merely pointing out the mistake in a comment distracts from the question at hand, as has happened here. There is a meta topic on the subject: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/spelling-mistakes-in-questions

Comment: @phipsgabler I figured as much, and maybe that is the standard expected in StackExchange, so certainly I'll ask as a separate question, but I figured if it was "on-the-way" for anyone, I'd put the question out there.

Comment: @Stephie I saw that 'planetmaker' said "please", so I obliged.  I maybe left "Moralitat" unedited, still, but I'm more than happy to change it upon request.

Do we have any possible answers for my question...?

Comment: @DavidVogt I totally agree. Yet here, it was not an honest mistake, but put there knowingly and deliberately for sake of lazyness (look up the version history - his words, not mine). Otherwise I'd simply edited it, yes, and not commented the way I did.

Comment: I'm all for corrections, too.  I personally just prefer to conserve my energies.  Thanks y'all for the lessons in etiquette...?  I would love some help with my question.  Please and thank you. :3

Answer (score 3):

Generally "außer-" means "not covered by" or "outside of". For example "**außer**gerichtliche Einigung" is a peaceful arrangement (Einigung) made without going to the court (Gericht).

I don't think you can create 5 sentences with the word "außermoralisch". If you google for it, you will most probably find only that one from Nietzsche. This word is not used in the everyday life, but more in the philosophic discussion.

I would like to quote from the book ["Grundbegriffe der Ethik" written by Alfred Simon, 1996](https://www.lehmanns.de/shop/nocategory/137594-9783211827109-fragen-der-ethik-in-der-psychotherapie)

> Es gibt auch Normen, die nicht zum Bereich der Moral gehören: Wer bei
> Rot über eine freie Kreuzung fährt, wer als Mann in Österreich einen
> Rock trägt, wer die Möglichkeit zu einer beruflichen Verbesserung
> ungenützt läßt oder wer beim Fußball einen Einwurf mit nur einer Hand
> ausführt, verstößt zwar gegen bestimmte Handlungsnormen, handelt aber
> nicht unmoralisch. Der Ethiker bezeichnet solche nicht-moralische
> Handlungsnormen als außermoralische Normen und meint damit Normen, die
> nicht zum Bereich der Moral gehören.

You can find some more definitions and examples reading first two pages of the chapter "Ethik und Moral" here:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-7091-3690-4_1